# double and integer variable in Calculator

Tags: android, integer, double, calculator

I am coding a calculator in Android
But a major problem for me to come
And it is that when I use **double-variable** equations
**For example, if the user enters 2 + 2 Print 4.0**
And when I use the **integer variable**
 **For example, if the user enters 2.1 + 2.2 Print 4**

While in the first equation to be printed 4
And in the second equation should be printed 4.3

However, the program does not understand any of this information

When i use double and integer variables in the equation
For example, integers Not calculating with doubles
While doubles Are calculating with integers!!

in windows apps, the program understand that when use double and when use integer variables to print answer

But Android is not so
is there a solution to this problem be solved?

this is the **code:**

```
package com.test.calculator;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button n1;
    private Button n2;
    private Button n3;
    private Button n4;
    private Button n5;
    private Button n6;
    private Button n7;
    private Button n8;
    private Button n9;
    private Button n0;
    private Button ndot;

    private Button nf1;
    private Button nf2;
    private Button nf3;
    private Button nf4;
    private Button nf5;

    private TextView txtshow;

    private Double v1;
    private String f;
    private Button cls;
    private Integer v3;
    private int point = 1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        point = 0;

        n1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n1);
        n2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n2);
        n3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n3);
        n4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n4);
        n5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n5);
        n6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n6);
        n7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n7);
        n8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n8);
        n9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n9);
        n0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n0);
        ndot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ndot);

        nf1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nf1);
        nf2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nf2);
        nf3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nf3);
        nf4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nf4);
        nf5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nf5);

        cls = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cls);


        txtshow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtshow);

        cls.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                point = 0;
                txtshow.setText("");
                f="";
                ndot.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });


        n1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtshow.setText(txtshow.getText() + "1");
            }
        });

        n2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtshow.setText(txtshow.getText() + "2");

            }
        });

        n3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtshow.setText(txtshow.getText() + "3");

            }
        });

        n4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtshow.setText(txtshow.getText() + "4");

            }
        });

        n5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtshow.setText(txtshow.getText() + "5");

            }
        });

        n6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtshow.setText(txtshow.getText() + "6");

            }
        });

        n7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtshow.setText(txtshow.getText() + "7");

            }
        });

        n8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtshow.setText(txtshow.getText() + "8");

            }
        });

        n9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtshow.setText(txtshow.getText() + "9");

            }
        });

        n0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txtshow.setText(txtshow.getText() + "0");

            }
        });

        ndot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                point = 1;
                if (ndot.isPressed()) {
                    txtshow.setText(txtshow.getText() + ".");
                    ndot.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });

        nf1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(txtshow.getText().equals("") && nf1.isPressed())
                {
                    txtshow.getText().equals("");

                }else {

                    if (point == 1) {

                        v1 = Double.parseDouble(txtshow.getText().toString());
                    }
                    if (point == 0) {

                        v3 = Integer.parseInt(txtshow.getText().toString());
                    }
                    f = "+";
                    txtshow.setText("");
                    ndot.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });

        nf2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(txtshow.getText().equals("") && nf2.isPressed())
                {
                    txtshow.getText().equals("");
                }else {

                    if (point == 1) {

                        v1 = Double.parseDouble(txtshow.getText().toString());
                    }
                    if (point == 0) {

                        v3 = Integer.parseInt(txtshow.getText().toString());
                    }
                    f = "-";
                    txtshow.setText("");
                    ndot.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
        });

        nf3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(txtshow.getText().equals("") && nf3.isPressed())
                {
                    txtshow.getText().equals("");
                }else {

                    if (point == 1) {

                        v1 = Double.parseDouble(txtshow.getText().toString());
                    }
                    if (point == 0) {

                        v3 = Integer.parseInt(txtshow.getText().toString());
                    }
                    f = "*";
                    txtshow.setText("");
                    ndot.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
        });

        nf4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(txtshow.getText().equals("") && nf4.isPressed())
                {
                    txtshow.getText().equals("");
                }else {

                    if (point == 1) {

                        v1 = Double.parseDouble(txtshow.getText().toString());
                    }
                    if (point == 0) {

                        v3 = Integer.parseInt(txtshow.getText().toString());
                    }

                    f = "/";
                    txtshow.setText("");
                    ndot.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
        });


        nf5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(txtshow.getText().equals("") && nf5.isPressed())
                {
                    txtshow.getText().equals("");
                    ndot.setEnabled(true);

                }
                if (point == 1) {

                    if (f != "" && txtshow.getText().toString() != "") {
                        Double res = null;
                        Double v2 = Double.parseDouble(txtshow.getText().toString());
                        txtshow.setText("");

                        if (f == "+") {
                            res = v1 + v2;
                        }
                        if (f == "-") {
                            res = v1 - v2;
                        }
                        if (f == "*") {
                            res = v1 * v2;
                        }
                        if (f == "/") {
                            res = v1 / v2;
                        }

                        txtshow.setText(res + "");
                        ndot.setEnabled(false);

                    }
                }

                if (point == 0) {

                if (f != "" && txtshow.getText().toString() != "") {
                    Integer res2 = null;
                    Integer v4 = Integer.parseInt(txtshow.getText().toString());
                    txtshow.setText("");

                    if (f == "+") {
                        res2 = v3 + v4;
                    }
                    if (f == "-") {
                        res2 = v3 - v4;
                    }
                    if (f == "*") {
                        res2 = v3 * v4;
                    }
                    if (f == "/") {
                        res2 = v3 / v4;
                    }

                    txtshow.setText(res2 + "");
                    ndot.setEnabled(false);
                }
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `in windows apps, the program understand that when use double and when use integer variables` Not really. It's the IDE which interprets what bad programmers should write in a decent way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use double in all calculation but when you going to view answer at that time you should do something like this

```
    int temp = (int) answer; //answer in double
    if(temp==answer){
     //set your answer that is in temp.
    }
    else if(temp<answer){
    //set your answer that is in answer variable.
}
```

if you get answer `5.5` in answer variable than in temp you will get `5` so else if condition will execute and your answer will be printed `5.5` but if you get `answer=5.0` than in `temp = 5` so if condition will execute and answer will be printed 5.